# Suppose that a person becomes unemployed. What is the probability that this person also was college educated?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have this question that I am having a hard time understanding. And how I should go about regarding questions like this. Could someone explain how my thought process should be regarding questions like these or help me out?

**Question:**

> Unemployment is affecting different groups differently. According to a American survey the unemployment on a national level was $13\%$, but only $6\%$ for people with a college education. Suppose that $21\%$ of the people in the workforce that is college educated. Now suppose that a person becomes unemployed. What is the probability that this person also was college educated?

The answer should be $9.7\%$, but I can't figure out how to get to this number.

Comment: This is a standard application of Bayes Theorem.

Comment: The question is asking you to divide the percentage of people who are both unemployed and college educated by the percentage of the population that is unemployed.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. You need to calculate $$P(C|U) = \frac{P(C\cap U)}{P(U)}$$
   where U, C are Unemployed and College grads respectively. (This is just the definition of conditional probability if you are not sure)
2. Now, we know 6% of C are in U. ie, $$|U\cap C| = 0.06|C|$$ And we know |C| is 21% of the population.
3. We also know |U| so you can calculate 1. to get ~9.69%

Comment: The notation $|S|$ is usually used for the number of elements in set $S$ rather than its probability.

Comment: Yes. The probability is $|S|$/population in this case(or can be left as percentages. It cancels out anyways). I assumed this was understood. @N.F.Taussig

Comment: The numerator should be $\Pr(C \cap U) = \Pr(C)\Pr(U \mid C)$, where $\Pr(U \mid C)$ is the probability that a person is unemployed given that she or he is college educated.

Comment: The question asks for prob. that the person is C, given that the person got unemployed. Why would you want to calculate the opposite? If you're only talking about calculating $|C\cap U|$(or its probability), we are doing the exact same thing using sets above. @N.F.Taussig

Comment: $\Pr(C \mid U) = \Pr(C)\Pr(U \mid C) = \Pr(U)\Pr(C \mid U)$.  We are given $\Pr(C)$ and $\Pr(U \mid C)$, and $\Pr(U)$, and wish to find $\Pr(C \mid U)$ from the given information.  I wrote an answer explaining how it is done.   It seems to me that you solved the problem intuitively the way I did.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I'm saying you can do the same thing by drawing out Venn Diagrams instead of using the definition twice. Either way, both are correct so it's fine

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ be the event that the person is unemployed.

Let $C$ be the event that the person is college educated.

We are given the following probabilities:
\begin{align*}
\Pr(U) & = \frac{13}{100}\\
\Pr(C) & = \frac{21}{100}\\
\Pr(U \mid C) & = \frac{6}{100}
\end{align*}
where $\Pr(U \mid C)$ is the probability that a person is unemployed given that she or he is college educated.

Then we are asked to calculate $\Pr(C \mid U)$, the probability that a person is college educated given that he or she is unemployed.

By definition,
$$\Pr(C \mid U) = \frac{\Pr(C \cap U)}{\Pr(U)} \tag{1}$$
The probability that a person is both college educated and unemployed can be found by multiplying the probability that the person is college educated by the probability that he or she is unemployed given that he or she is college educated, that is,
$$\Pr(C \cap U) = \Pr(C)\Pr(U \mid C)$$
Substituting $\Pr(C)\Pr(U \mid C)$ for $\Pr(C \cap U)$ in equation 1 yields
$$\Pr(C \mid U) = \frac{\Pr(C)\Pr(U \mid C)}{\Pr(U)} \tag{2}$$
You can complete the problem by substituting the given numbers into equation 2.